# Text-align:justify in IE8 - Text moves when clicked on or highlighted

Tags: internet-explorer, text, alignment, justify

I came with a problem with IE8 text displaying, that the justified text moves a little bit once I click on it or highlight it.

Exactly like this http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/ieBugs/floattext.html, except that my div has pixel width. It seems like an IE bug.

My question would be, has anybody ever come with this problem? How did you fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because your margin is in percentages - %
Fix it with pixels or something not relative!
This 2% calculation is moving actually, maybe other value in % may fix it either.